# Auto initialize rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

I'm always making the same steps when I do:

```
script/console
```

do you know some file to edit or something similiar to avoid doing always the same, like for example loading some particular required gem (in my casi 'spawners' :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a file called .irbrc in your home directory and any Ruby code you put in there will be executed at the beginning of your console session. There's lots of cool improvements you can make to the console experience this way, e.g. [these from Dr. Nic](http://drnicwilliams.com/2006/10/12/my-irbrc-for-consoleirb/) (the end of that article also has instructions for getting .irbrc working in Windows).

Comment: really cool, thanks a lot, I thinkg that my question was pretty basic :) thanks!

Comment: Mm.. I'm having a problem... I have this in my irbrc

require 'rubygems'
require 'irb/completion'
require 'map_by_method'
require 'what_methods'
require 'pp'
require 'spawners'
IRB.conf[:AUTO_INDENT]=true

but spawners is not working :( any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with spawners. Does it work if you just type in "require 'spawners'" after your session begins?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to stop doing :) When I do script/console, then I do _require 'spawners'_ all the time.. and adding require 'spawners' to irbrc is not working because my env is not loaded at the time that the irbrc is executed :(

Comment: Sorry, I haven't got a solution. I'd recommend debugging your .irbrc like you'd debug any other Ruby code, to see if you can figure out if it's getting tripped up somewhere (start with removing everything except the spawners line).

Answer (score 0):

With irb, ~/.irbrc serves for that purpose. Not sure whether Rails console uses it though.